# Jquery json response value to a variable

Tags: jquery, json

url http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/convert/?q=USD-INR&compact=y

json response

```
{
  "USD-INR": {
    "val": 61.235
  }
}
```

Jquery

```
function convert_currency(){
    var currency = $('#convertor select').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data : {
            q : 'USD-' + currency,
            compact : 'y'
        },
        url : 'http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/convert/',
        success : function(data){
            var value = data[0].val;
            $('#converted_amount').text(value);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    convert_currency();
    $('#convertor select').change(function(){
        convert_currency(); 
    })
});
```

but my method not correct. `var value = data[0].val;` . please correct me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var value = data["USD-INR"].val;
```

---

Since you've assigned currency value to the `currency` variable, you can do:

```
var value = data["USD-" + currency].val;
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this way

```
data["USD-INR"].val
```

So your ajax will be like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : {
        q : 'USD-' + currency,
        compact : 'y'
    },
    url : 'http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/convert/',
    success : function(data){
        var value = data["USD-INR"].val;
        $('#converted_amount').text(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `[0]`, because this is a generalized object, not an array. Use this, instead:

```
var value = data["USD-INR"].val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
function convert_currency(){
    var currency = $('#convertor select').val();
    var conversionSpec = 'USD-' + currency;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data : {
            q : conversionSpec,
            compact : 'y'
        },
        url : 'http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/convert/',
        success : function(data){
            var value = data[conversionSpec].val;
            $('#converted_amount').text(value);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    convert_currency();
    $('#convertor select').change(function(){
        convert_currency(); 
    })
});
```